# Reading file using Node.js "Invalid Encoding" Error

Tags: node.js, fs

I am creating an application with Node.js and I am trying to read a file called "datalog.txt." I use the "append" function to write to the file:

```
//Appends buffer data to a given file
function append(filename, buffer) {
  let fd = fs.openSync(filename, 'a+');

  fs.writeSync(fd, str2ab(buffer));

  fs.closeSync(fd);
}

//Converts string to buffer
function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}

append("datalog.txt","12345");
```

This seems to work great. However, now I want to use `fs.readFileSync` to read from the file. I tried using this:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('datalog.txt', 'utf16le');
```

I changed the encoding parameter to all of the encoding types listed in [the Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), but all of them resulted in this error:

```
TypeError: Argument at index 2 is invalid: Invalid encoding
```

All I want to be able to do is be able to read the data from "datalog.txt." Any help would be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: Once I can read the data of the file, I want to be able to get a list of all the lines of the file.

Comment: does `fs.readFileSync('datalog.txt', 'utf-16')` work?

Comment: richytong nope same error, sorry.

Comment: fs.readFileSync('datalog.txt') should work fine. I faced this when by mistake didn't use `path.join` in this code `fs.readFileSync(__dirname, 'file_path')` .. here valid  code would be `fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'file_path'))` and it works :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a few hours of troubleshooting a looking at the docs I figured out a way to do this.

```
try {
    // get metadata on the file (we need the file size)
    let fileData = fs.statSync("datalog.txt");
    // create ArrayBuffer to hold the file contents
    let dataBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(fileData["size"]);
    // read the contents of the file into the ArrayBuffer
    fs.readSync(fs.openSync("datalog.txt", 'r'), dataBuffer, 0, fileData["size"], 0);
    // convert the ArrayBuffer into a string
    let data = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(dataBuffer));
    // split the contents into lines
    let dataLines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
    // print out each line
    dataLines.forEach((line) => {
        console.log(line);
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

Hope it helps someone else with the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Encoding and type are an object:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('datalog.txt',  {encoding:'utf16le'});
```

Comment: This does not work and causes the same error. Looking online, it seems that both passing just a string and passing the object are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Write
fs.writeFileSync('./customfile.txt', 'Content_For_Writing');


// Read
const file_content = fs.readFileSync('./customfile.txt', {encoding:'utf8'}).toString();

console.log(file_content);
```

> node index.js

Output:

```
Content_For_Writing

Process finished with exit code 0
```